# Java: How large String can be optimized to occupy less memory in serialized object?

Tags: java, string, serialization

I have the following class, which I wish to serialize and store in .ser file:

```
public class Memento implements Serializable {
    private String file_name;
    private String content;
    private Date date_of_change;

    public Memento(String file_name, String content) {
        this.file_name=file_name;
        this.content=content;
        date_of_change = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    }

    public String getFile_name() {
        return file_name;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public Date getDate_of_change() {
        return date_of_change;
    }
}
```

The thing is that "content" variable must contain really large Strings. When program serializes and writes object, the result file's size is bigger, than original file's size (from which text of "content" was taken). For example, original file size is 2.035 bytes; .ser file's size after one snapshot is 2.247 bytes.

That's not good if I want to store multiple snapshots of text there.

Do You have any suggestions, how large String can be compressed/optimized to less massive type? Or maybe the solution is on Stream/Writer level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider providing your own readObject and writeObject methods that compress the contents of the content variable during serialization.  See ZipInputStream/ZipOutputStream.